# VBA - SUMIFS - Incrementing row - error 1004

Tags: vba, increment, sumifs

I've just registered on the website and I'm sure I can get some help on the below issue (I'm not an expert in VBA)..

Briefly, I'm doing a macro that computes a total quantity (in column I, for each row) based on 2 parameters (column A and column G). I'm using a SUMIFS function, which works great for one cell. But, I'd like to automate it for every row, that becomes tricky for me..

Here is the code that works for cell I2 :

```
Sub quantity_aggregated()      
    Dim sht As Worksheet, LastRow As Long, i As Integer    
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row     
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("JDE_Greece")     
    Range("I2").Formula = "=SUMIFS(H:H,G:G,G2,A:A,A2)"
```

I want to keep it that way but integrate a For, starting at row 2 and finishing at the last populated row.

I thought (and tried) about some codes below, 3 different (the end is the same, incrementing i and close the macro) :

```
For i = 2 To LastRow     

'Range("I2").Formula = "=SUMIFS(H:H,G:G,Range(i,7),A:A,Range(i,1)"''      

'Range(i, 9).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("H:H"), Range("G:G"), Range(i, 7), Range("A:A"), Range(i, 1))'   

'Cells(i, 9).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(H:H,G:G, "'     

Next i      
End Sub
```

I understand the process but for each, there's a "method range of object global failed (error 1004)" that pops up. I'm sure it's something about defining the application, the object or something related but can't solve it.

Does anyone have any ideas ? It would be really great :)

Thanks a lot in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply apply the formula to the whole range `I`. since your references to `A2` and `G2` are *"relative"*, the formula will systematically adjust for each row in the range.

```
Dim sht As Worksheet, LastRow As Long
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("JDE_Greece")     
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row     
sht.Range("I2:I" & LastRow).Formula = "=SUMIFS(H:H,G:G,G2,A:A,A2)"
```

---

If you want to do it with a loop "for practice",

```
For i = 2 To LastRow
  sht.Range("I" & i).Formula = "=SUMIFS(H:H, G:G, G" & i & ", A:A, A" & i & ")"
Next i
```

but notice that this is exactly what happens behind the scenes in the first form.

Comment: Hi,

Indeed, this works, and it's definitely faster... Spent so much time on this loop that I've almost forgotten the simple things. Thank you. 

But, by any chance, do you have any clue on why this loop doesn't work ? And what would a simple code look like if I want to insert a loop (i'd like to practice).

Thanks for your time

Comment: "@Jeofbist3 with a loop the formula would be composed as `"=SUMIFS(H:H, G:G, G" & i & ", A:A, A" & i & ")"`

Comment: @Jeofbist3 without accepting answers it's hard for anyone to keep helping you. Please consider my comment above. The "Thank you" button is by turhing the greu checkmark on the topleft of the answer into green. Thanks.

Comment: A.S.H  It seem like the OP doesn't care. People still help out. There are numerous comments reminding him, and yet... Have checked all his posts. Most answers, have been very useful. The questions, on the other hand are mostly marginal, though I wouldn't consider any of them outright down-votable. Will be keeping an eye out for some that are!  In the meantime he is going on my blacklist of people whose questions I won't answer. (And @Jeofbist3.)